# How can I translate keywords of algorithmic package?

Tags: algorithms

How do I translate standard keywords of the `algorithmic` package like (**if**, **then**,...) to my language?

If possible, I would like to do it without looking into source of `algorithmic` or `algorithm`.

Comment: I couldn't find any `algorithmic` package. Do you mean `algorithms` package ?

Comment: @percusse: I think so ;-)

Comment: @percusse: Hmmm.. yes it was `algorithmic` environment ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to look into the source code. The [documentation of algorithms](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) has an extra section with the following introduction:

> In order to facilitate the use of this package with foreign languages,
>   all of the words in the output are produced via redefinable macro
>   commands. The default definitions of these macros are:

```
...
\newcommand{\algorithmicend}{\textbf{end}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicif}{\textbf{if}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicthen}{\textbf{then}
...
```